# F# type inference with recursive functions and pattern matching

Tags: f#

I have the following F# code

```
let Operation (l:int list) =
    let A,B = l.[0], l.[1]
    if A > B then (-)
    else if A%2=0 && B%2=0 then (*)
    else (-)

let m =
    function
    | [] -> []
    | x::rest -> rest

let rec ops (l:int list) (opList:int->int->int list) =
    let operation = Operation l
    if l.Length = 0 then opList
    else ops (m l) (operation::opList)
```

Compiler complains at the last line saying

> This expression was expected to have type
>       'int -> int -> int list'     but here has type
>       ''a list'

It is underlying `(operation::opList)` but operation has the type `int -> int -> int` and opList has the type `int->int->int list`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int->int->int list
```

is equivalent to

```
int->int->(int list)
```

This is a function of two ints that returns a list of ints.

What you mean to write is:

```
(int->int->int) list
```

This is a list of functions of two ints that return an int.

So:

```
let Operation (l:int list) =
    let A,B = l.[0], l.[1]
    if A > B then (-)
    else if A%2=0 && B%2=0 then (*)
    else (-)

let m =
    function
    | [] -> []
    | x::rest -> rest

let rec ops (l:int list) (opList:(int->int->int) list) =
    let operation = Operation l
    if l.Length = 0 then opList
    else ops (m l) (operation::opList)
```

Comment: Wow, What a small but important detail. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, also you can just omit the type annotation altogether: `let rec ops l opList =` and F# figures it out by itself and lets you know what it thinks it is.